# the connection to localhost had been refused 22 port

Tags: ubuntu

when I start Hadoop using this command

```
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

so I try it to solve the problem by signing to the localhost, but the connection refused, and the problem message was:

```
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

the same message
so I searched in many websites and used these commands

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

I got this error

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Package openssh-server is not available, but
>   is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is
>   missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>   E: Package openssh-server has no installation candidate
>   tried to do update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

got this error:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Sources
Err http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/main Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/restricted Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/main Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/restricted Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/universe Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/multiverse Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/multiverse Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/main Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/restricted Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/main Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/restricted Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/universe Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/multiverse Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/multiverse Sources
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/main Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/universe Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/multiverse Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Help please

Comment: It means ssh server is not running. Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/518879/sshd-daemon-not-running-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: thank you 
but I got this error again
E: Package openssh-server has no installation candidate

Comment: Maybe you should edit the profile `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use the repositories that you have the fastest connection.
see also:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors